# Android Front Camera not Saving Photo to supplied URI

Tags: android, camera, uri, photo

I'm using standard code to start a Camera intent in my App with a URI supplied for the External Pictures directory.

If users click the button and take a photo using the normal camera, everything is perfect.

however if Users click the button, then when the camera app (Samsung Galaxy Tab A 9) opens, if they choose to swap to the Selfie Camera. When they take a photo, and confirm it, it will never be saved on the device.

The there is no file at the supplied URI, there is no photo in the Gallery.

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem with an s7, now the path to the image does not arrive because it is not saved in the device, you can take the bitmap in the following way and save it yourself.

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
```

Link: [You can find more details in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)